# Issues with text rendering in react component

Tags: json, reactjs

So I am working with an API, and found this in the documentation:

```
let message = {
 "text" : "<i>or</i> HN: the Next Iteration<p>I get the impression that with Arc being released a lot of people who never had time for HN before are suddenly dropping in more often. (PG: what are the numbers on this? I'm envisioning a spike.)<p>Not to say that isn't great, but I'm wary of Diggification. Between links comparing programming to sex and a flurry of gratuitous, ostentatious  adjectives in the headlines it's a bit concerning.<p>80% of the stuff that makes the front page is still pretty awesome, but what's in place to keep the signal/noise ratio high? Does the HN model still work as the community scales? What's in store for (++ HN)?",
  "time" : 1203647620
}
```

So in react (using function component), what is the proper way of rendering `message.text`? I am asking because my rendering output still has the tag `<i></i>` and `<p></p>` in the text when I return `{message.text}`. So I guess there is something wrong.

Comment: Check [dangerouslySetInnerHTML in docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render a string containing html you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

In your case will be:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: message.text }} />
```

Watch out using this attribute because it could expose your app to XSS attacks. (check https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)